# ngFor with Data binding?

Tags: data-binding, typescript, angular

I've got a *ngFor where I fetch a heroes list.
Now, If I change a value of hero, my heroes should be changed too, how do you do it, the best way...

```
     <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
      <input type="text" [value]="hero.name"/>
    </li>
```

I only know the way to make a (change)="UpdateListByItem(item)" , to call a methode, but isn't there a way to make a two way databind for all items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do two way databinding using ngModel directive

```
<li *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="hero.name"/>
</li>
```

Whenever you change the input text the corresponding hero name will get changed.

More information can be found here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: You can also debug the changes being reflected by adding {{heroes|json}} in the top of your template

Comment: What if heroes gets new elements? Should the list be updated too?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ngModel` to do this automatically

```
<li *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="hero.name"/>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [Answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/jW5YUm5D30DPMg2pUYYp?p=preview).
***ngModel*** allows to change individual name and update the list immediately.

```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#hero of heros">
            <input type="type"  [value]="hero.name"  [(ngModel)]="hero.name" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```